# How do I install Weston and use the Weston-calibrator on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wayland, weston

How do I install Weston and use the Weston-calibrator on Ubuntu 22.04 I do not see clear documentation for it.

Comment: Assuming you mean Weston = the reference implementation of a Wayland compositor: the package name is simply **weston**. Please note that Ubuntu and its Gnome Desktop uses the Mutter display manager as a compositor. Not sure what happens when it try to install another compositor. Please remember that Weston is only a compositor, you  need additionally a display manager.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know that. I am trying to set the calibration on a Toughbook running Ubuntu. Using libinput you can calibrate your touchscreen on Wayland compositors. See the libinput documentation.

If you have weston installed, you can use the weston-calibrator utility to get the transformation matrix. You can then apply it using a udev rule.

Comment: Well, based on the [Ubuntu package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/weston) the Weston package doesn't conflict with any of the Gnome packages or Mutter specifically. Which normally means you can install in parallel However, at least for myself I'm always cautious when playing around with possible low level changes in the system.
The **weston** package for Ubuntu does indeed include the program **weston-calibrator**, too.